# Quarto Project specify port for localhost

Tags: localhost, rstudio, port, quarto

Whenever I render a quarto project in rstudio by hitting the "render"-button it uses a random port for the localhost. The [manual](https://quarto.org/docs/reference/projects/options.html) states one can insert:

```
project:    
     preview: 
       port: 4200
```

However, despite having inserted this option to the `_quarto.yml` a random number is still used.

Any hints on what I am doing wrong? My underlying problem is I need to know the port number for usage inside of the knitting job. So I'd like to fix it to a number known to myself. Another solution would be to read the used port number out. But I couldn't figure out how to do that either. Would appriciate any help for a solution! Thx :)

Comment: Doesn't work on the Visual Studio Code extension for me either.

Comment: Same experience with VSCode and Quarto 1.4.550. This issue has been reported: https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/8965